# Check object for exact field match and only true values

Tags: javascript

How can I check if an object has the exact elements with `true` values?

This should be valid...

```
var checkIt = { 4: true, 15: true, 30: true, 75: true, id: 'anyString' };
```

...while those are invalid:

```
var checkIt = { 4: true, 15: false, 30: true, 75: true, id: 'anyString' };
var checkIt = { 4: true, 15: true, id: 'anyString' };
```

As a result I need `true/false` for this check.

Comment: This is easily accomplished with a standard `if` statement.  What problem are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach (ES6):

```
var props = [4, 15, 30, 75];
var isValid = props.every((prop) => checkIt[prop] === true);
```

... or, ES5 version:

```
var isValid = props.every(function(prop) {
  return checkIt[prop] === true;
});
```

With this you can easily adjust the list of properties to check. Using `every` makes sure the check drops out right after encountering the first invalid property.

Note: you aren't quite clear on whether or not each property should be exactly `true` or just truthy; I assumed the former. If that's not the case, just drop `=== true` part.